# How to display the message below the comboBox dropdown

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

I created a comboBox,

```
var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
    data : [
        {"abbr":"AL", "name":"Alabama"},
        {"abbr":"AK", "name":"Alaska"},
        {"abbr":"AZ", "name":"Arizona"}
    ]
});

Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
    store: states,
    queryMode: 'local',
    valueField: 'abbr',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    // Template for the dropdown menu.
    // Note the use of "x-boundlist-item" class,
    // this is required to make the items selectable.
    tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
        '<tpl for=".">',
            '<div class="x-boundlist-item">{abbr} - {name}</div>',
        '</tpl>'
    ),
    // template for the content inside text field
    displayTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
        '<tpl for=".">',
            '{abbr} - {name}',
        '</tpl>'
    )
});
```

below the drop down I wanted to display some messages.

Can anybody give some idea which component I will use or how to display some message below the drop down. Please check in screenshot.

[image: ScrrenShot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the `renderTpl` of `Ext.view.BoundList`, like:

```
listConfig: {
            renderTpl: [
                '<div id="{id}-listWrap" data-ref="listWrap"',
                ' class="{baseCls}-list-ct ', Ext.dom.Element.unselectableCls, '">',
                '<ul id="{id}-listEl" data-ref="listEl" class="', Ext.baseCSSPrefix, 'list-plain"',
                '<tpl foreach="ariaAttributes"> {$}="{.}"</tpl>',
                '>',
                '</ul>',
                '<div style="border: solid 3px #000; padding: 2px;">Message</div>',
                '</div>',
                '{%',
                'var pagingToolbar=values.$comp.pagingToolbar;',
                'if (pagingToolbar) {',
                'Ext.DomHelper.generateMarkup(pagingToolbar.getRenderTree(), out);',
                '}',
                '%}', {
                    disableFormats: true
                }
            ],

        }
```

Working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/23g4

Comment: Thankyou for answer. Is there any alternate in ExtJS 3.

Comment: Hi @CD.. can you please explain this code a bit? i really want to understand this properly.

Comment: @HarshitShah I've added a `<div>` at the bottom of the original `renderTpl`.